# Star formation after big bang doesn't violate entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, stars

Ok I know this has been asked a lot but I'm still a bit confused. 
After big bang, there are a lot of equally distributed elementary particles around with evenly distributed heat(or photons). So why doesn't the universe stays at this max entropy and instead opted to form star, only to distribute heat evenly again?
Please direct me to an answer if it exists.

Comment: Flagged as [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/117205), see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131204).

Comment: A quick search for "gravity decrease entropy" gives many results, such as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225340/why-doesnt-the-separation-of-particles-by-mass-via-gravity-decrease-entropy), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334406/entropy-and-gravitational-attraction) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280955/why-do-the-4-forces-of-the-universe-also-happen-to-increase-the-entropy-of-the-u)

Comment: Entropy of a system can decrease if it experiences work to change the state.